# JWT Authorization and Refresh token in .NET 5 Web API

Tags: authentication, jwt, .net-5, webapi, refresh-token

I have created JWT authorization/authentication service in .NET 5 Web API project and front-end on Angular 11 , one issue I have faced is with refresh token functionality. When I send request for refresh token . [I am using Validate Token function which is in JwtSecurityTokenHandler class provided by Microsoft and it throws exception if token is expired already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er2rg.png)  , So my question is , should I send refresh token request before it expires or not ? and if not how can I disable Token expiration check in Validate Token function or should I write my own version of that function ?

Comment: Please don't include code as images. Instead, paste as text, and format with Markdown. This makes it easier for the community to read and copy the code, if needed, and also improves both search results and accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily disable token expiration check. Just create new `TokenValidationParameters` and set `ValidateLifetime` to false. Something like this

```
public ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string jwtToken)
{
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = configuration["security:audience"],
        ValidIssuer = configuration["security:issuer"],
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = GetIssuerSigningKey(),
        ValidateLifetime = false //here we are saying that we don't care about the token's expiration date
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken securityToken);
    var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
    if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");

    return principal;
}
```